# Query on an array-type column that contains an array of strings including null in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using Sequlize with PostgreSQL as database in a Node-Express app. My table has a column and it's type is array of string. My goal is to find rows that contains a given array in that column. Current query -

```
const response = await MyTable.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
        topics: {
            [Op.overlap]: values
        }
    }
});
```

Now, some of the rows contains `NULL` as a value. My problem is, if I add null in `values` array, the query does not return the rows containing `NULL` value in that column.
For clarification, here in the target row, `topic = {NULL,SOME_VALUE,OTHER_VALUE}`
and in the query `values = [null,'SOME_VALUE']`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show SQL-query that corresponds to this Sequelize query?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE topics && ARRAY[NULL,'b73fd725-6112-475d-9071-682ab7c1d462']::VARCHAR(255)[];` - something like this (It looked a bit complex with other parameters. i simplified it) @Anatoly

Comment: If you have not-null values on both sides you should get `true` as a result of `overlap` comparison

Comment: Yes. It works fine for not-null values. But, if any row have `NULL` value and I want to fetch them, it does not work.

Comment: Yes, because `NULL` is not a value and `NULL` can't be compared with `NULL` like any usual values. `select null=null` returns NULL ad not true or false

Comment: Thanks. So, is there a solution to this? I am currently doing an workaround by replacing `NULL` with a predefined string.

Comment: I don't see better workaround than yours.